# Ansible loop with IP increasing IP addresses

Tags: ansible

The code below gives the correct hostnames per VM, but sends two IP's to the newly created VM. Everything else configures correctly on the VM. It does create two VMs `vm-vrf115` and `vm-vrf116` and gives them each two IP's. I am not sure why I am getting two IP's for each VM.

```
vm-vrf115 IP1: 192.168.1.115 and IP2: 192.168.1.230
vm-vrf116 IP1: 192.168.1.116 and IP2: 192.168.1.231
```

```yaml
---
- name: Create a VM from template and customize
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:

    ip_base: "192.168.1."
    starting_index: 115
    num_vms: 2
    hostname: vm-vrf

  tasks:

  - name: Create VMs
    delegate_to: localhost
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: vcenter_name
      username: administrator@vsphere.local
      password: vcenter_pw
      validate_certs: False
      datacenter: NSX-T
      folder: VRF-VMs
      name: "{{ hostname }}{{ item }}"
      state: poweredon
      template: Ubuntu-2204-Template
      esxi_hostname: pcs-esxi1
      disk:
      - size_gb: 100
        type: thin
        datastore: esxi1
      hardware:
        memory_mb: 4096
        num_cpus: 2
        num_cpu_cores_per_socket: 1
        scsi: paravirtual
        memory_reservation_lock: no
        # mem_limit: 8096
        mem_reservation: 0
        # cpu_limit: 8096
        cpu_reservation: 0
        hotadd_cpu: True
        hotremove_cpu: True
        hotadd_memory: True
        #version: 19 # Hardware version of virtual machine
        boot_firmware: "efi"     
      networks:
      - name: DPortGroup
        hostname: "{{ hostname }}{{ item }}"
        dns_servers: 
        - 192.168.1.3
        ip: "{{ ip_base }}{{ starting_index + (item | int) }}"
        netmask: 255.255.255.0
        gateway: 192.168.1.1
      wait_for_ip_address: no
    with_sequence: start={{ starting_index }} count={{ num_vms }}
    register: deploy
```

I've tried looking at the output, no errors, VM's configure fully. Just send two IP's for each VM, which is strange.

Is there something wrong with the way I configured the loop here?

Comment: I have the assumption that you description is missing what is actually the expected result. I think a single IP only, but which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is there something wrong with the way I configured the loop here?*

Using a minimal example based on your initial question

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    ip_base: "192.168.1."
    starting_index: 115
    num_vms: 2

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ip_base }}{{ starting_index + (item | int) }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    with_sequence: start={{ starting_index }} count={{ num_vms }}
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********************************
ok: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=115) =>
  msg: 192.168.1.230
ok: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=116) =>
  msg: 192.168.1.231
```

the answer seems to be no and if the expected result is to have the start index of `115` be added with index item of `115` and `116`, resulting into `230` and `231`. However, it would explain a possible configuration mismatch since you are going to do configuration in a distributed environment and on remote hosts.

If not and which I assume, you may have a look into the following changed example

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ip_base }}{{ starting_index + ansible_loop.index0 }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    with_sequence: start={{ starting_index }} count={{ num_vms }}
    loop_control:
      extended: true
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ********************************
ok: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=115) =>
  msg: 192.168.1.115
ok: [localhost -> localhost] => (item=116) =>
  msg: 192.168.1.116
```

To summarize, you probably unintentionally adding the loop item content to the base instead of the loop index or counter.

**Further Documentation**

- [Migrating from `with_X` to `loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence)
- [Extended `loop` variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)

Comment: Thank you! That was it! It works now. I was so close too, but couldn't get past how to set the index for initial count, and that was my issue. Thanks again!